# Insert data into two tables, linking the records together

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a record for a user.

Here are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(254) NOT NULL,
  passhash character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  email_verified boolean,
  time_created integer,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE user_info
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  first_name character varying(255),
  last_name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Basically when a new user signs up, I need add a record to users and user_info.

Normally I would run all of the queries seperate, something like this:

First insert into users:
`INSERT INTO users (email, passhash, email_verified, time_created) VALUES (...);`
Then find the `id` of the last insert: `SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND time_created = '$tm';`
And then insert into users using the `id` I retrieved in the last query: `INSERT INTO user_info ...`;'

I was wondering if this is an acceptable way to do this, I know there must be a better way.

Comment: Why two separate tables? If two tables, where is the foreign key?

Comment: Two seperate tables because there will be much more information in the future, figured it would be better to have them seperate? Is foreign keys something I should use? Not familiar with them, nor an sql expert.

Comment: A two table design is the best practice if you're expandning. Have you thought about creating a trigger? http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `returning` clause:

```
WITH u as (
      INSERT INTO users(email, passhash, email_verified, time_created)
          VALUES (...)
      RETURNING *
     )
INSERT INTO user_info(userId, . . . )
    SELECT u.id, . . .
    FROM u;
```

Comment: You add the appropriate columns and values where the `. . .` are.